# Entity Framework SaveChanges function won't commit my changes

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, savechanges

I have an initial selection which I place into list. I use the list to loop through each record and where it meets certain criteria  I run trough a series of inserts, deletes and updates. Finally call the SaveChanges() method to commit changes.

The code runs through without raising an exception but no changes reflect in the database. I have been searching the web with no luck.

I'm using VS2008 with SQL2008 backend.

Please help?

```
            using (SMSEntities db = new SMSEntities())
        {
            try
            {

                //Get SMS's to send from Inbox
                List<Inbox> tmpInbox = (from c in db.Inboxes where c.Status != "NEW" && c.Status != "SUCCESS" select c).ToList();// new { Inbox.InboxID, Inbox.StatusTrackingID, Inbox.Status, Inbox.NoOfAttempts, Inbox.CellNo, Inbox.SourceCellNo, Inbox.Header, Inbox.Message, Inbox.MessageDate, Inbox.AccountID, Inbox.LastAttemptDate }).ToList();

                foreach (Inbox tmpInboxIndex in tmpInbox)
                {
                    bool success = false;

                    //Check status here
                    string SentStatus = CheckSMSSentToProvider(tmpInboxIndex.StatusTrackingID);

                    // Define a transaction scope for the operations.
                    using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
                        {
                        try
                        {
                            if ((SentStatus == "DELIVERED") || (SentStatus == "NOTFOUND") || (SentStatus == "DELETED") || (SentStatus == "REJECTED") || (SentStatus == "UNDELIVERED"))
                            {

                                //Insert the Log row
                                Log newLog = new Log();
                                newLog.InboxID = tmpInboxIndex.InboxID;
                                newLog.CellNo = tmpInboxIndex.CellNo;
                                newLog.SourceCellNo = tmpInboxIndex.SourceCellNo;
                                newLog.Message = tmpInboxIndex.Message;
                                newLog.Header = tmpInboxIndex.Header;
                                newLog.MessageDate = tmpInboxIndex.MessageDate;
                                newLog.AccountID = tmpInboxIndex.AccountID;
                                newLog.ProcessedDate = DateTime.Now;
                                newLog.Status = tmpInboxIndex.Status;
                                newLog.StatusTrackingID = tmpInboxIndex.StatusTrackingID;
                                newLog.NoOfAttempts = tmpInboxIndex.NoOfAttempts;
                                newLog.LastAttemptDate = tmpInboxIndex.LastAttemptDate;
                                db.Logs.AddObject(newLog);

                                //Delete the Inbox row
                                if (tmpInbox != null)
                                {
                                    var deleteInbox = (from c in db.Inboxes where c.InboxID == tmpInboxIndex.InboxID select c).FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (deleteInbox != null)
                                    {
                                        db.DeleteObject(deleteInbox);
                                        //db.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Update inbox status 
                                var tmpUpdateInbox = (from c in db.Inboxes where c.InboxID == tmpInboxIndex.InboxID select c).FirstOrDefault();
                                tmpUpdateInbox.Status = SentStatus;
                                tmpUpdateInbox.NoOfAttempts = tmpInboxIndex.NoOfAttempts + 1;
                                tmpUpdateInbox.LastAttemptDate = DateTime.Now;
                                //db.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
                            }
                            // Mark the transaction as complete.
                            transaction.Complete();
                            success = true;
                            //break;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            // Handle errors and deadlocks here and retry if needed.
                            // Allow an UpdateException to pass through and 
                            // retry, otherwise stop the execution.
                            if (ex.GetType() != typeof(UpdateException))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("An error occured. "
                                    + "The operation cannot be retried."
                                    + ex.Message);
                                break;
                            }
                            // If we get to this point, the operation will be retried.
                        }
                    }

                    if (success)
                    {
                        // Reset the context since the operation succeeded.
                        //db.AcceptAllChanges();
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }

                // Dispose the object context.
                db.Dispose();

            }

            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                throw new Exception("ERROR - " + exp.Message.ToString(), exp);
            }
        }
        return true;
```

Regards,
GPR.

Comment: Why `db.SaveChanges();` is outside of transaction scope?

Comment: why are you posting code with commented out lines in it?

Comment: Hey Mitch, Appologies, I've been pulling my hair ourt trying to commit the changes that I've tried a hole bunch of stuff. Just forgot to remove the comments before posting this uestion

Comment: @Alex, I followed the transaction scoping example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx). Their SaveChanges method call is outside the transaction scope.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a local database file? You may be looking for changes in the wrong place. By default, when the program starts, VS copies the database file into the debug or release folder. Then the program runs and changes are made, and saved, to the file in the debug or release folder. The program ends, and when you look at the database in your source folder it looks the same. You can change the connection string in the app.config to use an absolute path to avoid this.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx for more info

Answer (score 0):

The TransactionScope is useless if you do not put the call to SaveChanges into it. 
Either move the call to SaveChanges into it or remove the TransactionScope completely.

Comment: I followed the transaction scoping example (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx). Their SaveChanges method call is outside the transaction scope.

Comment: I've tried moving the SaveChanges call within the transaction scope, but still no luck